# Hash sum mismatch error while upgrading 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS version from software update GUI

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I am receiving the below error during the process of fetching new packages while upgrading to 20.04 LTS from the software updater GUI

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-0_2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file: SHA512:2b363cb6eddc94084a1ed898942b312eb83cd06156d0de9a896bd64419cfcbb3ab91a10ddbbead1b03c20bfabcdc319835eee14608567238a57a54d477b8abbf
  SHA256:b38c57344c28f1d61b520285ec0cdeaf15d5c4992dfce4414df5d553990b3ee4
  SHA1:7327ced461c3ab00d557eacad792b300bb1903ca [weak]
  MD5Sum:6b84a2f9d260376cbf47ee655dd2a104 [weak]
  Filesize:1286892 [weak]
Hashes of received file:
SHA512:b7b8f3b73a2c8e25a94396be637718a9ab2ebd9de1dc9977cc8bed96e9f88299e9e80775e1328cebe52436a8f2e2cae2a97437ac144e27af04d58b27ea120336
  SHA256:740b63a11650ef23717381034110a84086c7931692c3d6b3ed97aa58d9fef4ee
  SHA1:6f13b00971f16817325891801e6446726c2ee931 [weak]
  MD5Sum:48c4391e7e13f8746b92b64c9a59c413 [weak]
  Filesize:1286892 [weak]
Last modification reported: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 21:33:47 +0000*
```

I have tried doing following

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then again trying to upgrade from software upgrade GUI
It again fails with the same issue mentioned above
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It means the file contents isn't what it should be. Double-check that your internet connection is good, and, given a hash mismatch, do this on a private/trusted network do decrease the risk of this being an MITM attack. See if it still happens on a private, trusted, _and reliable_ network.

Comment: @cocomac my internet is working fine, i did try it multiple times, mine is a private local internet provider, not sure what exactly is the issue

Comment: Maybe change where it downloads from on the `Download from:` in the Software & Updates.  Maybe try the Main Server.

Comment: it worked when i changed the internet network provider to my mobile one,strange it worked!!